# Threejs - How can I curve text to prevent bloated corners?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Without curved text, the corners become quite thick and unfavourable.
I am trying to curve to text so the corners don't appear distorted. How can this be achieved?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain (in your post) what you mean with "curved text" (what curves? the baseline? straight lines in each glyph? 3D spherical projection?) and what you mean with "the corners"? The corners _of what_? And can you either annotate your image, or pick one that clearly shows off the problem you're asking about? This one seems... unrelated? It's just a bunch of 3D extruded text with a mesh cube.

Comment: Use shapes of letters instead of volume letters: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_text_shapes